# My cat cannot close one of his eyes

Tags: cats, eye-disease

My cat is 1 year and 10 months old. He is a white doll-face Persian cat, with yellow-brown eyes. He is eating very healthy and eats three times a day.

Since yesterday I am noticing that he is not closing his Right eye frequently. Even when he blinks he is not closing the right eye. Also yesterday night I found some (more than usual) Eye gunk/boogers/dirt on the side of his Right eye. Not on the side of the nose, but the right side of the Right eye. I cleaned up with wet tissue paper.

Today, I think it is even worse. Even now that he is sleeping, his Right eye is not closed. It is closed to some extent but not fully closed like the left eye. And while I tried to close it, the right side eye bag comes down after some time. It seems like the eye bag is just hanging.

However, I cannot open his left eye, because he is closing it. But I can easily open his right eye.

Is it an infection or even worse Paralysis? But his eyes are not red or anything like that.

I am really scared for him. And because of this Covid pandemic, everything is in lockdown. Could you please suggest to me what could be the issue and what steps I should take to prevent it? I will try to find a vet tomorrow and let the doctor examine him properly. But if you could also suggest anything I will be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: I voted to close the question because as you already realized yourself this is a problem that needs professional care. Make sure you get a vet appointment as soon as possible, if your local vet is unavailable you can always call an emergency clinic/vet and ask them what to do.

Comment: @SerenaT Yes, I will be going to the vet tomorrow no matter what. But I just thought if someone had any such similar experience maybe they also could suggest me some advice or provide additional tips to care. Because not all pets have similar behaviour and some pets need a different way to care for them. I don't see why that is wrong? Anyways, you take care.